# jsonnet conditional generation of a field

Tags: jsonnet

How can I get something like this working in jsonnet?

```
{
    if 1 == 1 then
      store: true
}
```

I get the below error when I run it with jsonnet:

```
STATIC ERROR: a.jsonnet:2:9-11: unexpected: if while parsing field definition
```

I would like to generate a json like this, just as an example, but while evaluating some conditions:

```
{
  "store": true
}
```

Comment: Do you also want to conditionally create the field rather than just its value ? If the latter something like `{ store: 1 == 1 }` or `{ store: if 1 == 1 then "TRUE" else "FALSE" }` would do it. If you need the field itself to be conditionally present (as suggested by the question's title), it gets a bit more complex.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I need the field itself to be conditional present.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below snippet implements conditional `store_A` and `store_B` fields, corresponding to `val_A` and `val_B` values, ab-using jsonnet `[null]` evaluated *fieldname* to remove it from being manifested

```
local exp_val = 1;
local val_A = 1;
local val_B = 0;

{
  [if val_A == exp_val then 'store_A']: true,
  [if val_B == exp_val then 'store_B']: true,
}
```